# Fragment layout not fully inflating upon FragmentTransaction.add/replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, nested

I am attempting to replace a nested fragment inside a tabLayout fragment.

My app structure follows this pattern.

[image]

Here is the XML for the Tab Fragment 2

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scene_root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shows_fragment_list"
        android:tag="list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shows_fragment_details"
        android:tag="details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shows_fragment_info"
        android:tag="info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am using this code to add the NestedFragment to the TabFragment FrameLayout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shows_fragment_layout, container, false);

    ShowDetailsFragment newNestedFragment = new ShowDetailsFragment();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .add(R.id.show_fragment_details, newNestedFragment)
            .addToBackStack("null")
            .commit();

    return root;
}
```

But when I add the Nested Fragment to the Tab Fragment, only the last part of my layout appears, in this case it is a list view (highlighted in red), but it always seems to be the which ever element is declared last when the layout is inflated by the corresponding Java file.

[image]

When I inflate these layouts as there own activity, there are no inflation problems, so it must relate to my implementation of fragments, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to add the second fragment inside the onCreateView of the first one?

Comment: When I call onCreateView of Tab Fragment 2, that is when I try to do Fragment.Transaction.add NestedFragment.. as Tab Fragment 2 is just a shell for a set of Nested Fragments

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is always to use the Android Device Monitor to debug your layout.

I would also add some logging on the onCreateView of your fragments.

Comment: All the code in my onCreateView is being read, I believe that all the elements of the layout are just being drawn on top of each other.

Comment: The scene_root layout is a FrameLayout. That means that only one of the three children layout will be displayed. You have to set visibility to gone to the other two children to be sure to see always the one fragment you expect.

Comment: ctarabusi - While this is certainly good advice, unfortunately this was not the cause of my problem, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my problem was that in my XML layout for my ShowDetailsFragment (The Nested Fragment) I had a FrameLayout as the root, but there were two separate RelativeLayouts as children, meaning only the last element was being displayed, the problem was solved by nesting these two Relative Layouts in another single Relative Layout.

Props go to ctarabusi for pointing me in the right direction, although I am still unsure why this only caused a problem when inflating as a Fragment and not as an Activity.